# Dedicated grapics card in laptop doesn't work

Tags: kernel, radeon, amd-graphics, integrated, linux-headers

So, graphics card is R5 M330. It doesn't work under radeon nor under amdgpu. Using Ubuntu 16.10. Integrated GPU is working flawlessly

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` command returns this :

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R3 Graphics]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Mullins [Radeon R3 Graphics]
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

`lspci -v` returns this error:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
        **!!! Unknown header type 7f**
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

output of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` :

```
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD HAINAN (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.10.0-041000rc8-generic, LLVM 3.8.1)
```

The same problem appears under Fedora and OpenSuse.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Both adapter work with `radeon`. What is the real problem?

Comment: Accidentally deleted "Unknown header type" part, if header type is unknown doesn't that mean that device is not in use?

Comment: This message does not mean it does not work. How do you know it does not work?

Comment: I believe that I've had same error message on the wifi adapter when it wasn't working.

Comment: Please run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears` and see what happens.

Comment: Also please add the output of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` to your question.

Comment: I get blank window, also you can see that I've updated Linux kernel, but that problem appears on every kernel.